# Rotating Rectangle with mouse isn't consistant

Tags: java, swing, rotation, awt

The following example draws 2 Rectangles.

Within the paintComponent() method, the first Rectangle is draw normally and the second Rectangle is rotated.

Rotation is based on the mouse movement. If the mouse is clicked on the rectangle and then moved 
in a circular fashion, the 2nd Rectangle rotations as expected, but as the mouse rotations around, the rotation of the Rectangle isn't always in sync with the mouse.

I suspect this is all related to the angle calculation. Any suggestions on how to get the rotation of the Rectangle to be in sync with the mouse movement?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class SimpleTest extends JComponent 
{
    static int x = 200,y = 200 , width = 100 , height = 30;
    static Vector objectsToDraw = new Vector();
    static int mouseClickX, mouseClickY, mouseX, mouseY = 0;
    static double angle;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //Create Frame
        JFrame window = new JFrame();

        //Attach Mouse Listeners.
        window.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {  }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
            {
//              System.out.println("Dragged");
                System.out.println("Dragged at X :" + e.getX() + "   Y : " + e.getY());
                calculateAngle(e.getX(), e.getY());
                mouseX = e.getX();
                mouseY = e.getY();
                window.repaint();
            }

        });

        window.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) { }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) { }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0)  {  }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Pressed at X :" + e.getX() + "   Y : " + e.getY());
                mouseClickX = e.getX();
                mouseClickY = e.getY();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) 
            {
                System.out.println("Released");
                mouseClickX = 0;
                mouseClickY = 0;
                window.repaint();
            }   

        });

        //show Window
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setBounds(30, 30, 800, 800);
        window.getContentPane().add(new SimpleTest());
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void calculateAngle (int x, int y) 
    {
        int deltaX = x - 250;//Rectangle Center X
        int deltaY = y - 200;//Rectangle Center Y
        angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX));
        System.out.println("Angle = " + angle);
    }   

    @Override //Works
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        System.out.println("paintComponent() - using angle : " + angle);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();
        g.drawRect(x,  y,  width,  height);
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), 250, 215); 
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 30);
        g.drawRect(x,  y,  width,  height);
        g2d.setTransform(old);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is great. Thanks. It took me a bit to compare the two samples and determine that actual issue. 
It appears there were 3 problems with the original code. 1) Using JComponent instead of JPanel. 2) Attaching the Mouse Listeners to the Window instead of Panel. 3) Including the super.paintComponent() call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, you're adding the MouseListener to the *wrong* component. Don't add it to the window but rather to the JComponent that does the drawing.  Otherwise, your mouse positioning will be off by however large the menu bar is, or any other components that changes the position of the drawing component (the component that *uses* the mouse positions) relative to the JFrame (your component that currently *gets* the mouse positions).

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleTest2 extends JPanel {
    // avoiding "magic" numbers
    private static final int PREF_W = 500;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    public static final int RECT_X = 200;
    public static final int RECT_Y = RECT_X;
    public static final int RECT_WIDTH = 100;
    public static final int RECT_HEIGHT = 30;

    private double angle;

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SimpleTest2 mainPanel = new SimpleTest2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Test 2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();  // let the GUI size itself
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    public SimpleTest2() {
        // using an adapter is a nice clean way of avoiding empty method bodies
        MouseAdapter myMouse = new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                calculateAngle(e.getX(), e.getY());
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                calculateAngle(e.getX(), e.getY());
                repaint();
            }

        };
        addMouseListener(myMouse);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
    }

    public void calculateAngle(int x, int y) {
        // get rid of "magic" numbers
        int deltaX = x - (RECT_X + RECT_WIDTH / 2);// Rectangle Center X
        int deltaY = y - (RECT_Y + RECT_HEIGHT / 2);// Rectangle Center Y
        angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        // better way to size the drawing component
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);  // ***don't forget this guy***
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        // for smoother rendering
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();
        g.drawRect(RECT_X, RECT_Y, RECT_WIDTH, RECT_HEIGHT);
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), 250, 215);
        // Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 30);
        g.drawRect(RECT_X, RECT_Y, RECT_WIDTH, RECT_HEIGHT);
        g2d.setTransform(old);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I learned a few important items about painting with this answer and plan to continue testing a few things using this code.